# Xmpp ejabberd custom authentication with nodejs

Tags: node.js, ejabberd

I want use XMPP ejabberd server with node js authentication, but I didn't find any docs or tutorial about it, where can I find example?

Comment: did you find any script? the page till no support for nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to authenticate using a database it's easier if you use auth_odbc, if you still wanna just do it through nodejs you can translate any of the examples from: http://www.ejabberd.im/extauth